# Joomla 3.X | Change the layout of the fields on the module

Tags: php, html, xml, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to customize the layout of the fields in the various tabs of my custom form but I can't find the php file that generates these fields.

For now I have seen that in Joomla the fields of the various options are generated by the my_module.xml file but I would need the PHP file.

Where can I find it?
Otherwise, is it possible to recall the various fields in a custom.php file?

To be clear, this is the result I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Comment: Jack, did you give up on this question?